# ImageMagick: Vertically Center Text?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to vertically center text in an image using ImageMagick.

For example, I want an image that's 200 pixels high with the word, "TEST," vertically centered in the image.

And I don't want to specify the width of the image. I want ImageMagick to compute the image width based upon the width of the text.

The -extent parameter requires both width and height so I can't use that.

I'm using ImageMagick 6.4.0 01/19/10 Q16 for Cygwin. This appears to be the latest Cygwin version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify width in `-size` parameter and use [label](http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#label):

```
convert -size x200 -background red -gravity Center \ 
        -pointsize 10 label:"TEST" test.png
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't quite do it. The -size attribute applies to the text as well. So this creates an image with TEST in a 200 point font. The -pointsize attribute is totally ignored.

Comment: But maybe it's the version I'm using. In which version does the above correctly create an image with TEST centered and in a 10 point font?

Comment: That's strange. I've tested with different pointizes and it worked. Maybe you should update IM to the latest version? I use `ImageMagick 6.6.9-2 2011-03-31 Q16` (for Windows).

Comment: Yes, it works properly in the latest Windows version! Thank you!

Comment: Be sure to check answer if it helped.